# Reset Color field to default value

Tags: 3d-view

Sorry if I am asking a dumb question but I was not able to find a solution. So I change the background color of the viewport from viewport header option. Now I want to reset it. there is an option of reset to default value but it is not interactable. how can I reset the values to default ?? thanks

Comment: That's actually a good question and I'm interested in the anser, too. Normally, if you hover over a value and hit _Backspace_ it resets the field to the default value. In _Prefrences > Themes_ where you can set the colors, right-clicking a color has an option "Reset to Default Value (Backspace)" in the context menu - but no matter on which color I try it, it sets them all to black. And this certainly isn't correct. Maybe a bug?

Comment: Thank you, back space worked for the values but for the colors it just turns into black... I am confused why "Reset to Default values" is not clickable...